# Connected sum of real projective planes as a torus or sphere.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the connected sum of four real projective planes: $\mathbb{R}P^{2} \# \mathbb{R}P^{2} \# \mathbb{R}P^{2} \# \mathbb{R}P^{2}$. How to present this space using spheres, tori and $\wedge$ or $\vee$ operations or products?

Please help me, with this problem.

Comment: What is the Euler characteristic of this space?

Comment: The Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{R}P^{2} \# \mathbb{R}P^{2} \# \mathbb{R}P^{2} \# \mathbb{R}P^{2}$ equals $0$, because $\chi(\mathbb{R}P^{2})=2$, $\chi(S^{2})=2$. 

I used the following formula: $\chi(M_{1} \# ... M_{4})=\chi(M_{1})+...+\chi(M_{4})-2\chi(S^{n})$, where $n$ denotes the dimension of $M_{i}$ for $i=1,...,4$.

Comment: Sorry, Euler characteristic of this connected sum equals $4$. This is also Euler characteristic of $S^{2} \times S^{2}$. But is there another simpler proof of this fact (without using Euler characteristic)?